# Bash Script commands inside a program

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, vpn

Please excuse me if this is too simple for you, but I really did my search before posting this question. I am trying to create my first bash script for auto connecting on my softether vpn. To manually connect I follow these steps;

```
sudo ./vpnclient start
sudo ./vpncmd
```

then it asks me a question of selections from 1 to 3, I pick 2 and hit enter. Then it asks me something else and I just hit enter.
Then;

```
AccountConnect ofis
exit
sudo dhclient vpn_vpn_se
sudo ip route add X.X.X.X/32 via 192.168.1.1
exit
```

Now I this is my amateur script but I guess something is wrong because it comes to part where I am supposed to pick an option from 1 to 3 and it does nothing after that part.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/burock/vpnclient
sleep 1
sudo ./vpnclient start
sleep 1
sudo ./vpncmd
sleep 1
printf "2\n"
sleep 1
printf "\n"
sleep 1
printf "AccountConnect ofis\n"
sleep 1
exit
sudo dhclient vpn_vpn_se
sleep 1
sudo ip route add 46.1.131.30/32 via 192.168.1.1
sleep 1
exit
```

Could you help me out? I guess it won't type "2" and hit enter because it is under vpncmd command. Or I am doing it all wrong... I also tried to give 1 second pause between each command. I am using Lubuntu btw, if it matters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Once you run a command like `sudo ./vpncmd`, control doesn't return to your script until the command exits (or forks itself into the background). Only at that point do your `printf` commands get executed, sending their output to the terminal as usual.

You can try instead something like

```
{ sleep 1
  printf "2\n"
  sleep 1
  printf "\n"
  sleep 1
  printf "AccountConnect ofis\n"
} | sudo ./vpncmd
```

or (if the `sleep`s aren't strictly necessary) just

```
printf '%s\n' 2 "" "AccountConnect ofis" | sudo ./vpncmd
```

and so on, but if that fails you may need to script the interactive session with something like `expect` or `autoexpect`

Comment: You sir are a legend! Thank you very much, those curly brackets and pipe did miracles! Now I know that bash can only control terminal but not the app unless we use those brackets and pipe!