# Running a command inside a gnu screen from a bash script

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm currently trying to run a command in a detached gnu screen from bash, but simply using

```
screen -r myscreen
mycommand
```

doesn't work. Detaching from the screen after executing the command isn't necessary since the command is used to gracefully exit the program.

I also tried using

```
{ 
  mycommand
} | sudo screen -r myscreen
```

like answered on the post [Bash Script commands inside a program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354650/bash-script-commands-inside-a-program), but this returned `Must be connected to a terminal`, along with a command not found error.

Is there a way to execute a command in a gnu screen from bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`man screen`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/screen.1.html):

> ```
>    -S sessionname
>         When creating a new session, this option can be used to specify a meaningful name for
>         the session. This name identifies the session for screen -list and screen -r actions.
>         It substitutes the default [tty.host] suffix. This name should not be longer then  80
>         symbols.
>
>    -X   Send the specified command to a running screen session. You may use the -S option  to
>         specify  the  screen session if you have several screen sessions running. You can use
>         the -d or -r option to tell screen to look  only  for  attached  or  detached  screen
>         sessions. Note that this command doesn't work if the session is password protected.
> ```

So you could use:

```
screen -S myscreen -X your-command
```